# File Permission issue javac

Tags: java, java-8, ubuntu-14.04, file-permissions

I have files in a directory. Some have root as the owner and group and some user (me) as owner and group (however that happened). I ran `sudo chmod 755 -R /usr/casloader`, all my directories are under `/usr/casloader`. All files are `-rwxr-xr-x`.

I am trying to compile a java class (as me the user) - if run the javac on a  file that owner/group is `root`, I can compile fine. The owner/group of the compiled class becomes me. (it writes the compiled class into the same folder).

But if I try compile a class that owner group is me it gives `file write error: Permission Denied`.

How do I solve this? Does everything have to be root?

Comment: That's not because you are the group owner. Probably because the class file already exists with root as the owner. But you don't provide enough information to determine. In any case, use `chown` as root to make all the *.java files your, then delete all *.class files, then try again.

Comment: The message clearly says that this is a write issue, so the ownership of the files being read is irrelevant. Since you apparently have write permission to the target directory, you can remove all existing class files, regardless of their owner, then compile again.

Comment: @Erwin @Holger the ,class file I am trying to create did not exist, so there is no overwrite situation right now( in future it may happen when I recompile).  I `chown` the the .java file to root and was able to compile (the group is still me). When I tried recompiling got error, deleted the .class file. Trying to recompile now, but now I get same old write permission error. The owner of file is root group me.

Comment: My sub-directories all are also rwxr-xr-x root root

Comment: So your subdirectories are all writable by root only. I'm not sure why you expect to be able to write a file created by your non-root user in a directory that is owned and writable by root only.

Answer (score 1):

I just did g+w,o+w with a -R. so I have rwxrwxrwx - so the problem is solved. (Not sure if this is the most optimal solution.)